# mutex for multiple threads via queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, thread-safety, mutex

I am trying to share data between two threads via a queue. One thread pushes into and the other pops from the queue. I got to know that it is safe to have synchronization between the threads and hence decided to use mutex. Every forum i see has a #include "mutex" statement in the code, but i get "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mutex': No such file or 
directory", when i use it. Please let me know what is this error due to.

I am using a Windows machine and Visual Studio 2005 compiler.

Answer (score 7):

> I am using a Windows machine and Visual Studio 2005 compiler.

`std::mutex` declared in `<mutex>` header is not available before C++11. Just upgrade your compiler to VS 2012 which [should support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh921467.aspx) (as I see this is tagged with `visual-c++`).

If upgrade is not possible, as juanchopanza noted, you could use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html), or, if you're already using `CreateThread` and other system calls, you can create one by yourself using `CreateMutex` [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If an upgrade is not possible, using [boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html) might be a viable alternative.